# Self-Study Sufficient Statistics, Pdf with Indicator Function

Tags: order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

The example is from the Book [Hogg Introduction to Mathematical Statistics](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peach07up/stat420/master/(7th%20Edition)%20Robert%20V.%20Hogg%2C%20Joeseph%20McKean%2C%20Allen%20T%20Craig-Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Statistics-Pearson%20(2012).pdf) Page 384, Chapter 7.2 Sufficient Statistics. Please let me know if my argument for the solution is correct, since I used a different one then presented in the book.

Problem:

Let $X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < \dots < X_{(n)}$ denote the oder statistics of a random sample of sice n from the distribution with pdf:

$$
f(x;\theta) = exp(-(x-\theta)) \mathbb{I}_{[\theta, \infty)}
$$

Solution:

By factorization theorem: $L(X;\theta) = g(T(X), \theta)h(x)$:

\begin{align*}
L(x;\theta) &= \prod_{i=1}^nexp(-(x_i-\theta)) \mathbb{I}\{\theta < x_i < \infty\} \\
&= exp(-(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i- n\theta)) \cdot \mathbb{I}\{\theta < {x_i}_{(i=1,\dots,n)} < \infty\} \\
&= \mathbb{I}\{max\{X_i\} < \infty\}exp(-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)\cdot exp(n\theta) \cdot \mathbb{I}\{\theta < min\{X_i\}\}
\end{align*}

By factorization theorem:

$$
h(x) = \mathbb{I}\{max\{X_i\} < \infty\}exp(-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)
$$

and:
$$
g(T(X), \theta) = exp(n\theta) \cdot \mathbb{I}\{\theta < min\{X_i\}\} \Rightarrow T(X) = min(X)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes correct, but in a very simple way

$$f_X(x|\theta)=e^{\theta}e^{-x}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[\theta;\infty)}(x)$$

Now simple observing that (here $X_1,...,X_n$ are not ordered...)

$\theta \leq X_1<\infty$

$\theta \leq X_2< \infty$

...

$\theta \leq X_n< \infty$

thus it is self evident that

$$\theta\leq X_{(1)}$$

Thus the likelihood is

$$L(\theta)=\underbrace{e^{-\Sigma_iX_i}}_{h(\mathbf{x})}\cdot\underbrace{ e^{n\theta}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty;x_{(1)}]}(\theta)}_{g[t(\mathbf{x}),\theta]}$$

thus $T=X_{(1)}$

---

I edited your question because the order satistic is always written as $X_{(i)}$

Comment: ok thx, year, I wrote it out very explicitly, but that was also my intend. I'm struggling a bit with the indicator functions, so need to exercise a bit more. Thx again.